# How to send client side data to server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, ejs

I am using Geolocation API inbuilt in HTML5, But the main problem is that, I want to store result from the geolocation Api in my db. So my Main Question is that **how can I send this details or result to my main file (server side )?**

I made a empty form and through script tag I have inserted two input hidden tag and stores my result in it by using selecting tag by ID and simply change it's value to my desired result. But I am getting empty string in my backend file.

```
// EJS FILE 

<body>

    <p>Click to  get your coordinates.</p>

    <form action="/" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="lat"  id="lat" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="long" id="long" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="test" id="test"value="">
        <button type="submit" onclick="Onclick()">Try It</button>
    </form>

    <p id="demo"></p>

<script>

function Onclick(){

   var x = document.getElementById("lat"); 
   var y = document.getElementById("long");
   var z = document.getElementById("test");

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
           navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
            console.log(position.coords); 
            x.value =  position.coords.latitude 
            y.value =  position.coords.longitude; 
           });
    } else 
           z.value = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
}
</script>


(Please give me answer in JS only )
```

I am new to NodeJs, I searched a lot before posting this question, didn't get the required answer. I really appreciate your precious time for solving this queries.

When I click button and check it on server side ,Instead of getting desired result,I am getting empty values,Please help me on this part !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getCurrentPosition` is an asynchronous function, this means that:

1. You click the button
2. The `Onclick` function fires
3. The form submits
4. The callback function which sets the form values runs (or would if you hadn't left the page)

You need to avoid submitting the form until after the data is available.

- Bind your event handlers with `addEventListener`
- Prevent the default behaviour of the form
- Resubmit the form with JS once the data becomes available

```js
// Bind the event listener here
var form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener("submit", submit_geo_coords);

// Add the event paramater to the function
function submit_geo_coords(event) {

  event.preventDefault(); // Stop normal submission of the form

  var x = document.getElementById("lat");
  var y = document.getElementById("long");
  var z = document.getElementById("test");

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      console.log(position.coords);
      x.value = position.coords.latitude
      y.value = position.coords.longitude;
      form.submit(); // Resubmit the form when the data is available
    });
  } else
    z.value = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
}
```

```html
<p>Click to get your coordinates.</p>

<form action="/" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="lat" id="lat" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="long" id="long" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="test" id="test" value="">
  <button type="submit">Try It</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much brother for your help. I have one small doubt ,why console is not working in my ejs file ,not printing anything in my terminal or browser ,Can you please tell me why it is not working?

Comment: @Error404 — Because it (doesn't) run after the browser leaves the page to load the next one.